# Database reference to fill divs with information depending on drop down

Tags: javascript, html

I have a 2 drop downs and using javascript I have got it so that when the drop down changes on 1, the variable x becomes the value and y for the other. I also have divs and I want to know how I can create a database that, according to the drop down, fills the divs with specific information.

Taking into account whats above, these are my source code, I would like it so that when I select for example "Two" in my first drop down, it display the information related to "Two" in my divs below it. I have not created any information as I do not know how to declare and create a database so that I can use it for my purpose, here are my codes:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4yfeqoXUVzETjhVdkZpWnlwT00/edit
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4yfeqoXUVzEeU05UDFKdUN4b2M/edit

I hope you can access these and that you can help. Happy to be more specific if you tell me in which  way.

Comment: That is such a hugely broad question, without understand how your system is set up. Using the term "database" implies a server-side component. However the context of the rest of the question is about javascript / purely client side. Try to narrow down the statement, and give more detailed background information. Basically, keep in mind that questions on SO should be **specific** and show research / attempts to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well let me be the first to say to you that you pretty much just asked how to build a car. Haha! You have a lot of understanding to do before you can create your first database. I would start with [this article](http://www.ignoredbydinosaurs.com/2013/05/explaining-non-relational-databases-my-mom). It breaks down relation vs non-relational databases.

After you understand databases you are going to need to learn a language to communicate with the server. PHP is an option, but I would suggest using [Node JS](http://nodejs.org/) and the [MEAN stack](http://www.mean.io/#!/). The MEAN stack is very powerful.

But, to answer you question, the idea would be to store a unique value with in those drop down options. Then when the drop down options are selected, you grab that unique value from the front end and send it to the server. The server will respond with the information you want and then you can just some form of javascript, I would suggest Angular JS, to populate the page with the dynamic content.

In the mean time, if you have any other questions please feel free to ask.

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have read the article and am starting to learn PHP. Once I get further into it I may require your assistance. Once again thanks!